# PHP Auto pick time slot

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I have an array, where I have divided 24 hours in 3 slot (8 hours each)

```
<?php 
$timeSlot = [
    'A' => '06:00-14:00',    // 8 hr
    'B' => '14:00-22:00',    // 8 hr
    'C' => '22:00-06:00',    // 8 hr
];
```

How can I get current time slot (A/B/C) when my script is loaded?

Comment: Which of the start/end times is inclusive/exclusive?

Comment: Slot C will go to next date since it will exceed 00:00 (12AM)

Comment: That is not Luke's question. What slot is `14:00` in? A or B?

Comment: I'd start by re-structuring that array to have seperate keys for "start" and "end". Then compare with current time.

Comment: 'B' can be regarded from `14:00:01`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should give you what you need.

Reverse the array to loop it backwards and if the current time is more than the $time then we got a match.
When the loop ends we still don't know if "A" is actually "A" or "C".
Compare the time again and echo the $slot.

```
$timeSlot = [
    'A' => '06:00-14:00',    // 8 hr
    'B' => '14:00-22:00',    // 8 hr
    'C' => '22:00-06:00',    // 8 hr
];
$timeSlot = array_reverse($timeSlot);

foreach($timeSlot as $slot => $time){
    if(date("H") >= substr($time, 0,2)){
        break;
    }
}
if($slot == "A"){
    if(date("H") < substr($time, 0,2)){
        $slot = max(array_keys($timeSlot));
    }
}

echo $slot;
```

https://3v4l.org/MKf1H

Comment: During 6 AM to 7AM, it's returning C, but it should return A

Comment: Found the problem. I had `<=` when it should be `<`

Comment: @Amin does it work? Does it answer your question?

Comment: yes, it does. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $current_hour = date('h');
```

will return you current hour as per timezone. You can then use any conditional statement to assign slots.